# Why does PermissionsAndroid doesn't ask for permission again after denying in react native?

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

I am using PermissionsAndroid for taking permission from my user but the request popup doesn't show up again if I deny permission once.PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED automatically becomes false. Is there a way to make sure the request popup shows up when my customer presses the button?